# Facebook token permanent solution for insights data?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As of right now we have a couple facebook apps(different one for each client), all of which use extended user tokens to access insights data of campaigns and adsets.

Is there a way to get permanent access to campaign's insights information with a token that never expires? If not, should we just make a dashboard and nag-mail that makes us manually generate new tokens, or is there a way to generate new token and extend it programmatically?

Comment: A token only gives temporary access, you need to re-request a new token every time it expires. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) will tell you this. You can simply add an expire on the SQL table and run a check that it hasn't yet expired or just run a metric (check the response is *connected*) when attempting to read off the token. Re-authentication is a good thing, you should provide this even without expiry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exchange your token for a permanent one, just go to this url :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&fb_exchange_token=[TOKEN]
```

It will return a permanent token (until user revokes the application or change his FB password) and a "expires" value, but it's a permanent one, you can verify it's a permanent one by using the token debugger :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: It worked. One thing to note, if you are partnered with facebook they give you permanent tokens that never expire.